Can a proxy constructor replace the initializer used in upgradeable contracts?
I was wondering if a regular constructor could be used in the proxy of a proxy-implementation upgradeable contract, instead of an initializer in the implementation contract. If not, please explain why.

No, a proxy constructor cannot replace the initializer used in upgradeable contracts, because:

The proxy’s constructor is only responsible for initializing the proxy’s own state (e.g., storing the implementation address) and does not handle the state of the implementation contract.

Since the implementation’s logic can change during upgrades, its state must be initialized via an initializer function in the context of the proxy.


This ensures proper setup for each implementation version, which the proxy constructor alone cannot achieve.
